# Как посредством рефлексии менять поля класса-переменной?

Tags: java

Как мне изменить поля класса-переменной? Никак не получается. Пример кода:

```
public class Test {

   public Nested variable = new Nested();

   public class Nested {
      public String value = "";
   }

}
```

Нужно изменить поле класса "value" внутри переменной variable.

Мои попытки:

```
  Class parentClass = ...; // какой-то класс
  Class nestedClass = parentClass.getDeclaredField("variable").getType();
  nestedClass.getDeclaredField("value").set(nestedClass.newInstance(), "new value");
```

Либо выкидывает ошибку, что класс не имеет конструктора с нулевым аргументом, либо просто ничего не сетается в классе.

Comment: Пример кода как вы пытались это сделать через рефлексию - нужно прикрепить.

Если никак не пытались, то идите изучайте, и когда дойдёте до тупика в своей реализации, то просите помощи.

А вообще рефлексию лучше не дёргать для изменения значения т.к. рефлексия не поддаётся отладке.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас прикреплю